# How to adapt MTCNN to large images with relatively small ROIs

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, object-detection

This question could be generalised to how to adapt state-of-the-art object detection models to large images with small ROIs.

In my particular case I'm trying to use [this implementation](https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn) of [MTCNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02878.pdf) to get bounding boxes for the faces of images of statues.

One challenge is that the face could take up a large proportion of the image like this:

[image]

Or a very small proportion of the image like this:

[image]

Where I'll zoom in on the statue's face so you can see it:

[image]

**Bonus**

If anyone has additional comments on my overall approach to this particular problem, happy to hear them.

Comment: The paper approach use image pyramid with downscaling only. That create problem for big images with small faces. You may be able bypass it with brute force sliding window approach: 1. Train on upscaled low-res images 2. for big images apply detector in sliding subwindow on several scales, with subwindow upscaled to detector resolution.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to ditch MTCNN for a while in favor of an approach of getting the statue with Faster R-CNN, then we'll see where I go from there